# Smoothing function for PRM output

Tags: c#, smoothing

I've implemented a [Probabilistic roadmap method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_roadmap_method) function, which works and executes correctly. The only problem is that the output of the prm is not smooth for example, if a hand needs to rotate  from 30 to 100 degrees, the steps might be 30,55,42,66,99,100, i wat to be able to smoothen the transition betwen the 30 and 100 degree. I know that the problem is related tp smoothing of a signal yet i dont know what type of smoothing might be able to do the job. No sophisticated method is needed. My implementation is in c#, if possible i wish to let such job be done by a library. Is there any such library? which i can give it an array of integers and likewise produce an array of smoothed values.

Comment: do you have all steps at once and want to calculate a movement curve with constant velocity through all the positions or do you get the positions one after another?

Comment: the prm provides me with all the values i need, i just want to smooth it up. yes all the positions are one after the other

Comment: in your example you have: 30, 55 and then 42, do you want to do the movement back to 42 or the 42 before the 55 to have a strictly increasing curve?

Comment: the importance is that form 30 the value increases to 100, therefore it would be need that 55 is decreased between the 42 and 30

Comment: a stricter increasing curve the importance is between the end and the start values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a simple [curve fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) algorithm. A quick google search will give you lots of example code. And if you want to have a strictly increasing curve, you need to sort the values before you do the curve fitting.

If you are just interested in reaching the target, you can drop the values in between and do a linear interpolation from start to end or something similar.